# How to show iphone virtual keyboard when external keyboard connected

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I'm developing an app in Flutter. This means it runs in Android and iOS mobile devices.

In Android when you connect an external bluetooth barcode reader it lets you choose if you'd like to show the virtual keyboard or not.
In apple iOS devices (an i-phone 5 in my case) I'm not able to open it until I disable the bluetooth connection.

Is there any way to force the virtual keyboard to show in flutter?

Comment: `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod<void>('TextInput.show');` try this. I'm not sure this will work

Comment: The reader needs to have a "show keyboard" button. Keyboard emulating barcode readers aren't great  Readers that are a separate Bluetooth peripheral or using the device camera is often better.

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin your solution doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, your solution works but it requires some user deeper understanding. I was searching some other solution, thank you anyway