# How to force virtual keyboard to show even if physical keyboard is connected?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, keyboard, hardware

When an external keyboard is present, iOS refuses to display the on-screen virtual keyboard. This is logical however not desired for my use case.

I want to be able to force the virtual keyboard to show up on android and iOS devices even if an external device (which presents as a keyboard) is connected.

The use cases could include a joystick or controller that emulates WASD or arrow input, a barcode scanner, or a custom device that emits keyboard events that correspond keys to a specific observed event.

As a secondary question: how could one restrict or ignore the use of external keyboard events in certain situations? (For example, the user fills out a text field and bumps the joystick: I do not want the joystick's keyboard input to be considered)

I have already seen the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708169/how-to-show-iphone-virtual-keyboard-when-external-keyboard-connected), however, that question remains unsolved and I am optimistic that nearly three years on, there may be a new solution not yet posted.

Similar posts [here (trying to avoid the keyboard on Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035796/flutter-textfield-use-cause-keyboardlistener-alway-show-keyboard-on-event) and [here (trying to capture the input of an external barcode scanner into a textfield)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555472/flutter-bluetooth-external-barcode-scanner) are not solutions either. As far as I can tell this issue hasn't been adequately solved yet.

Thank you.